# Completing the squares

Tags: completing-the-square

If I have the following equation:

$$f = 2\gamma_2 \sigma_{2,1}^2 a^2 + 4 \gamma_2\sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,2}ax_2 + 2\gamma_2 \sigma_{2,2}^2x_2^2$$

I can write it as:

$$f = 2\gamma_2(\sigma_{2,1}a + \sigma_{2,2}x_2)^2$$

But now I have:

$$g = 2\gamma_1 \sigma_{2,1}^2 a^2 + 2 (\gamma_1 + \gamma_2)\sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,2}ax_2 + 2\gamma_2 \sigma_{2,2}^2x_2^2$$

Now I'd like to complete the squares, but I don't see how.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need to complete the square?  Solve for $x_2$, or something else?

Comment: I want to proof (if possible) that $g \geq 0$ for $\gamma_1 \geq  0$ and $\gamma_2 \geq  0$.

Comment: I suspect there's some meaning to the $\sigma$'s and perhaps the $\gamma$'s and $a$, that would help?  What do they represent?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
    g
    &= 2\gamma_1 \sigma_{2,1}^2 a^2
         + 2 (\gamma_1 + \gamma_2)\sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,2}ax_2
         + 2\gamma_2 \sigma_{2,2}^2x_2^2 \\
    &= 2(\gamma_1 \sigma_{2,1} a + \gamma_2 \sigma_{2,2} x_2)
       ( \sigma_{2,1} a + \sigma_{2,2} x_2)
\end{align}

Things are occurring in groups. Acknowledging them might clear away some of the noise.

Let $A = \sigma_{2,1} a$ and let $B = \sigma_{2,2} x_2$.

Then $g = 2(\gamma_1 A + \gamma_2 B)(A + B)$

You said you wanted to prove, if possible, that $\gamma_1 \ge 0$ and $\gamma_2 \ge 0$ implies $g \ge 0$. I'm going to have to assume that $A$ and $B$ can be any real number.

But if $\gamma_1 > 0$ and $\gamma_2 = 0$, then you get $g = 2 \gamma_1 A(A + B)$ which you can make negative if you make $A$ positive and $A+B$ negative.

So it seems that your hypothesis is false; unless there are things about $\sigma_{2,1} a$ and $\sigma_{2,2} x_2$ that you haven't told us about.